# What does the Sanskrit word "abhithiya" mean in the 2022 Booker Prize Winner The Seven Moons of Maali Almeida?

Tags: meaning, translation, shehan-karunatilaka, the-seven-moons-of-maali-almeida

I'm applying to be the Chinese translator of the 2022 Booker Prize Winner The Seven Moons of Maali Almeida. The publishing house asks me to undertake a sample translation. While completing the task I come upon a Sanskrit word that is rather confusing. Here is the context:

> ‘Those knots were looser than your Amma’s redda.’
> ‘What you say?’
> ‘Just there. Navam Mawatha, that hardware store sells masking tape. Would’ve taken five minutes.’
> ‘It’s not open.’
> ‘So go open it.’
> ‘Aiyo I can’t. The abhithiyas are waking. Can’t be punching priests early morning.’

In this scene, two Sri Lankans try to dump a body in the Beira Lake (Colombo). They are now discussing if they could get some tape at a nearby hardware store.

I wonder if anybody knows what 'abhithiya' means here? Could it be a misspelling of 'abhidheya'? Judging from the verb 'waking', it may refer to a type of person, but I don't know which type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been a surprisingly difficult question to answer. Online dictionaries and google searches provided no clue, so I asked a Sri Lankan acquaintance of mine. He, a Tamil, did not know either but thought that the word was probably of Sinhala origin. He in turn asked a Sinhala friend, and received this answer:

> I heard from a Sinhala friend of mine that the word refers to **young
> Buddhist priest novitiates**, so my guess was not wide off the mark.
>
> It is the practice of some parents in Sri Lanka, especially poor ones,
> to essentially give their young male children to Buddhist temples
> where they then live, as if in a boarding school. This way the
> children are not a financial burden on their parents and they are
> essentially groomed to become monks when they reach adulthood. These
> young children shave their heads and wear yellow robes like the monks.

This fits completely with the wording of the passage given in the question. It is early in the morning and the novitiates are waking up, and the characters don't want to attract attention and so have to be "punching priests". Note that there is a big Buddhist temple near Navam Maratha.

Comment: Many thanks! This explanation sounds very enlightening to me.